# Need clarification on the way a set former is written

Tags: automata, regular-language

I'm being asked to draw a DFA for the language specified by the following set former:

$$\{xabay\, |\, x \in \{a,b\}^*\text{ and }y \in \{a,b\}^*\}$$

Is this any different than the language specified by the set former:

$$\{xabax\, |\, x \in \{a,b\}^*\}$$

They seem equivalent to me, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing some crucial detail related to set former notation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first set former, we can have $x=a$ and $y=b$ whereas in the second one you are restricted to the first and last (group of) letters being the same.

I believe an equivalent statement would be

$$\{xabay\,|\,x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$

however don't quote me on that as my set notation is a bit sketchy and there's probably a small detail that I've forgotten about

Comment: Of course. If we don't specify different variables for the beginning and the end of the string, we're requiring the same string at the beginning and the end, which is a very different DFA. I feel like that should have been obvious... I believe that your set former notation is correct as well. Thanks.

Comment: It is not true that in the second language, the first and the last letter have to be the same. For instance, $baababa$ is a word of the second language.

Comment: OK, when I said letter, I was technically referring the group of letters which make up $x$...

Comment: That is the way I interpreted your answer, as referring to an example of how x and y could refer to different words, rather than as specifying that x and y represented specific symbols from the alphabet.

Comment: @Denis I know you understood but I guess it is right to be completely specific!

Answer (score -1):

Setting $A = \{a,b\}$, the first language can be represented by the regular expression $A^*abaA^*$. Thus it is the set of words having $aba$ as a factor and it is a regular language.

A word $u$ of the second language is also required to have $aba$ as a factor, but a stronger restriction is imposed: one should have $u = pabas$, where the prefix $p$ and the suffix $s$ are equal. This condition makes the second language not regular. Indeed, its intersection with the regular language $a^*abaa^*$ is equal to $\{a^nba^n \mid n > 0\}$ and I let you verify that this language is not regular.